# How could I know who's the first one on the queue?

Tags: logic

Given a number `N`, knowing that there is a queue of `T` people, determine who the person will be in the first place, if each iteration, the person in the first place, moves to the last place, and is also cloned.

For example:

`T => ["Susan", "Henric", "Patrick"]`

`N => 4.`

- T1 => ["Susan", "Henric", "Patrick"]
- T2 => ["Henric", "Patrick", "Susan", "Susan"]
- T3 => ["Patrick", "Susan", "Susan", "Henric", "Henric"]
- T4 => ["Susan", "Susan", "Henric", "Henric", "Patrick", "Patrick"]

Then, `Susan` would be the first on the Queue.

Is there a mathematical way to solve who will be in the first position? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: If you list the people in first place at times T0, T1, T2, ... you get S, H, P, S, S, H, H, P, P, S, S, S, S, P, P, P, P, H, H, H, H, ... do you see the pattern?

Comment: But if T1 => S, H P then T2 => H, P, S, S if n==2, then H would be the answer, I'm not able to understand the pattern, I can see there's 2^x being X each iteration, but that's not how the queue works, right?

Comment: Ok, well you edited your post. So my list above is the first place person at times T1, T2, T3, .... When n==2, H is the answer, and indeed H is the second person in my above list. When n==5, S is the answer, and indeed S is the 5th person in my list.

Comment: I see, your list works, but... How did you get it? I mean, your t3 I'll get once I have iterated 9 times the array... I'm a little silly for these things, I'm sorry